# Javascript console logging extended exceptions

Tags: javascript, exception, console

There are libraries that throw extended errors, for example GraphQl Apollo gives one. Trying to log it straight into console gives only the general title like "Server Error" hiding the details.

Is there a way to print error objects into console like other objects, allowing you to browse through it? Following code is a reproduction in code of the problem.

```js
class RError extends Error {
    constructor({name, message, cause}) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.message = message;
        this.cause = cause;
    }
}

function fail() {
    throw new RError({
        name: 'BAR',
        message: 'I messed up.'
    });
}

function failFurther() {
    try {
        fail();
    } catch (err) {
        throw new RError({
            name: 'FOO',
            message: 'Something went wrong.',
            cause: err
        });
    }
}

try {
    failFurther();
} catch (err) {
    // Prints "FOO: Something went wrong" and stacktrace, hiding the cause
    console.error(err);
    // It's still available if you know the path
    console.error(err.cause);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`console.error()` is basically aimed at displaying the error message. If want everything else simply use other [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console): `.log()`, `.dir()`, `.table()`...

```js
class RError extends Error {
    constructor({name, message, cause}) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.message = message;
        this.cause = cause;
    }
}

function fail() {
    throw new RError({
        name: 'BAR',
        message: 'I messed up.'
    });
}

function failFurther() {
    try {
        fail();
    } catch (err) {
        throw new RError({
            name: 'FOO',
            message: 'Something went wrong.',
            cause: err
        });
    }
}

try {
    failFurther();
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    console.dir(err);
    console.table(err); // Not implemented in Stack Overflow snippets
}
```

Comment: Log doesn't work. Dir and table do, thanks. I'll use console.dir when needed. I wonder if any way to have that colored, would be better to have errors orange or red.

Comment: Console is just an API. Each implementation works as it sees fit. If you don't like what your browser does, you can always write your own.